# ArgumentError wrong number of arguments logged_in? method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

I am having some trouble with a boolean method I coded following the Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl.

It's a logged_in? boolean method that returns true if theres a session open for a user. I honestly can't see where the syntax error is, hopefully someone can help me.

I receive this error

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

for this logged_in? method.

This is the code for the method:

```
def current_user           # Returns the current logged-in user (if any).
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
            @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
    elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
            user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
            if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
              log_in user
              @current_user = user
            end
    end
end

def logged_in?        # Returns true if the user is logged in, false otherwise.
    !current_user.nil?
end
```

The code where the errors show up are the following:

views/_header.html.erb

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
     <div>
        <%= link_to "sample app", root_path, id: "logo"%>
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav pull-right">
                <li><%= link_to "Home",    root_path %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Help",    help_path %></li>
          <% if logged_in? %>
            <li><%= link_to "Users", '#' %></li>
            <li id= "fat_menu" class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Account <b class="caret"></b>
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Settings", '#' %></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          <% else %>
                    <li><%= link_to "Sign in", signin_path %></li>
          <% end %>
            </ul>
        </nav>
     </div>     
    </div>
  </header>
```

You can see in line 9 that I called if logged_in? with no arguments, so I dont know why when I run the app, the browser shows an ArgumentError message for that line.

This was the trace:

```
    app/models/user.rb:28:in `authenticated?'
app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:19:in `current_user'
app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:27:in `logged_in?'
app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb___182677250_46999464'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:141:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:306:in `render_partial'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:279:in `block in render'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:278:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:47:in `render_partial'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:27:in `render'
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:12:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___794293552_47017152'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:141:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `render_with_layout'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `render_template'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:17:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:127:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:219:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:120:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:33:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:26:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:97:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `realtime'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:403:in `_run__621296767__process_action__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:680:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__685618970__call__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

In the trace we can see an authenticated? method. Here is its code:

```
def authenticated?  # Returns true if the given token matches the digest.
        BCrypt::Password.new(remember_digest).is_password?(user.remember_token)
    end
```

The definition of is_password? according to BCrypt sourcecode is the following

```
# Compares a potential secret against the hash. Returns true if the secret is the original secret, false otherwise.
    def ==(secret)
      super(BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(secret, @salt))
    end
    alias_method :is_password?, :==
```

It also showed my an argument error in the destroy action in the sessions controller as seen here:

app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb

```
  class SessionsController < ApplicationController
      .
      .
      .
      def destroy
        log_out if logged_in?
        redirect_to root_url
      end
    end
```

Any hints of where should I start digging? Thank you so much!!!

Comment: What about the `is_password?` method? How is it's definition?

Comment: is_password? is a method defined by BCrypt, I went to the BCrypt sourcecode and found the definition. I updated the question including it. You can also check the sourcecode here: https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/blob/master/lib/bcrypt/password.rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the sixth line of `def current_user` you have

`if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])`

that is, you are calling the `authenticated?` method with an argument (`cookies[:remember_token]`).

However, you are not declaring any arguments in your `authenticated?` method definition.

Comment: any == arguments. In other words, santib misread the error message. And santib didn't even post the whole error message(there is no mention of an ArgumentError). @santib, If you define a method, authenticated?() to take 0 arguments, you can't call it with one argument, cookies[:remember_token]. Next time post the whole error message.  Posting what you think the error message says is fine, but the WHOLE error message is REQUIRED.

Comment: Excellent! It worked great! I was using authenticated? instead of the authenticate() method. Thank you so much! and to everyone who got involved in trying to solve this :)

Comment: @7stud I am sorry, I will try to be more specific next time! I thought the title of the question "ArgumentError wrong number of arguments" was enough. My bad.

Comment: No need to apologise, I am sure @7stud just wanted to point you in the right approach to understand your errors. From my little experience I think it's better to "religiously" follow the trace from top to bottom in order to find where your bug is instead of giving a quick look at the whole trace and trying to guess yourself.

Comment: @sebkomianos Thank you! As a newbie here I am constantly learning about best practices so next time it will be better! One quick question.. what's the best way to obtain the whole error message, So I can just copy and paste it entirely when required?

Comment: @santib Most of the times the error message that you get in your browser is good enough. If not, just copy-paste the whole trace. You might also want to have a look at [better_errors](https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors)

Answer (score 0):

can you please clear the cache and run once again also can you show the method 
authenticated?
try user.authenticated or if !current_user.blank?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately that didn't work for me. You can see the definition of the authenticated? method in the question above.